# Place span element over buttton's title CSS

Tags: html, css

I have button with span, which represents a spinner

```
<button>
  Confirm
  <span class="spinner"></span>
</button>
```

So now it looks like this:

[image]

I would like the spinner to appears above the word "CONFIRM", i tried a lot with `position` attribute, but without any success, how could I fix it with help of CSS?

Comment: Try with before or after t o get solution

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: if you can wrap the confirm text in a span, you can use flex on the button and swap the order

Answer (score 1):

```css
.confirm {
 
  height:40px;
  text-align:left;
  position:relative;
}
.confirm .spinner {
  
  display:block;
  background-image: url(https://accountportal.cdph.ca.gov/images/loader.gif);
background-size: cover;
  position:absolute;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius : 50%;
  right:0px;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto ;
}
```

```html
<button class="confirm">
  Confirm <span class="spinner"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use position:absolute and left

```css
.confirm {
  width:100px;
  height:60px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}

.spinner{
    position:absolute;
    left:33px;
    content:'';
  display:block;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius : 50%;
  
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="confirm">
  Confirm
   <span class="spinner"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a button which have pseudo element as spinner. You can add or remove the progress icon by removing `showProgress` class on button. Here is the example

> Spinner is just come over the button text by using button pseudo element

```css
.showProgress::after {
    content: "";
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    border: 3px solid #0000ff4d;
    border-left: 3px solid #0039ff;
    background: transparent;
    animation: borderSpin 1s linear infinite;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-left: -39px;
}
.spinnerButton {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: white;
    height: 30px;
    width: 70px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes borderSpin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes borderSpin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<button class="spinnerButton showProgress" >CONFIRM</button>
```